# Transform the log scale into non-logarithmic scale in R

Tags: model, logarithm

I have created a linear model with logarithmically transformed y and x variables. Now i would like to plot the model but back transform the axis labels for better interpretation. How can i do this in R?

Comment: I would use the source data that you used to create the log values.

Comment: I used source values to create log values, but how can i now plot it that the axis are in a non-log scale?